# Use folder pattern in Spring MessageSource

Tags: java, spring

By default, Spring MessageSrouce add locales at the end of properties files. For example if my locale is en_CA, it tries to find /myMessages_en_CA.properties file.

I want to change it to folder pattern. For the above example, the location should be /en/CA/myMessages.properties. I am wondering if there is any way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

No because the name of the property files is defined in Java standard ResourceBundle.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

But you are free to implement your own MessageSource where you can use any files.